# Using Selenium + Python to login through pop up window

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, espn

I am trying to access and login to the following webpage using Selenium in Python:

'http://games.espn.com/ffl/leagueoffice?leagueId=579054&seasonId=2018'

When the page is accessed a pop up window appears asking for the user's credentials. The below code is what I have so far.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

user = 'test_user'
pw = '*********'

url = 'http://games.espn.com/ffl/leagueoffice?leagueId=579054&seasonId=2018'

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\abc\\Downloads\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)

obj = driver.switch_to_alert

time.sleep(5)

obj.find_element_by_name('email').send_keys(user)
obj.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(pw)
```

When I run it I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'
```

Based on other stackoverflow threads I thought I was approaching this correctly. Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Are you missing a function call? Like `driver.switch_to_alert()`?

Comment: Trying that gave me: 'NoAlertPresentException: no alert open'

Comment: Consider replacing the error message above with the new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elemets you're trying to interact with are ***located in another frame***. Using inspector you can see that they are inside `<iframe id="disneyid-iframe" name="disneyid-iframe"`

So before doing any actions, you need to **switch to** that frame:

`driver.switch_to_frame("disneyid-iframe")`

and then do what you need (**note:** I corrected locators to use type attribute since I didn't see that elements have name attribute)

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type = 'email']").send_keys(user)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type = 'password']").send_keys(pw)
```

Remember to switch back to default context after you are done interacting with elements from that frame:

`driver.switch_to.default_content()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this and Check:

```
obj.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]').send_keys(user)
obj.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="password"]').send_keys(user)
```

Also don't use time.sleep() module in selenium,keep a habit of using explicit waits.

Comment: Can you elaborate on using explicit waits? And with your solution I receive the follwing:'NoAlertPresentException: no alert open', which I take to mean that the pop up login menu is not considered an 'alert'

Comment: Remove this part 'obj = driver.switch_to_alert' and replace obj with driver in the following two statements and check.

Comment: **Explicit wait** reference: [selenium doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait)